# how can i change activity to other activity with specific fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have 2 activities and one navigation drawer in second activity.In the first activity I have container to replace fragment when click drawer item changing fragment in container.Now I want doing this in second activity:
when click on items in second activity change activity to first activity and show me specific fragment(for example favorite fragment) in fragment container.I can change the second activity to first activity with Intent but I can't replace fragment when do Intent.
this is one case of items:

```
case 2:
Intent intent2 = new Intent(LietnerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent2);
fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a Bundle in the Intent, which contains the tag of the Fragment you want to show. And when the first Activity onCreate(), get the tag and make the FragmentManager create or show the Fragment.